# jQuery Number Format- How to stop letters from accepting?

Tags: jquery

I used this  [number format jQuery](http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-number-format-redux/196/)

for displaying numbers with commas while typing. But when i typed letters also in the box, it's also taking as input. I need it to accept only numbers in and not letters, what to do?

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code...

Comment: If i need to display Investment Amount in format(with commas after every 3 digits and two decimal points while typing the walue) i use the below code in my jsp file after including jQuery where "investmentAmount" is the id of Investment Amount.



**$('#investmentAmount').number( true, 2 );**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this could be considered dirty, but instead of having to update the plugin yourself, just filter the keys first:

$('#bla').on('keypress', function(evt) {
    var code = evt.which || evt.keyCode;

```
if (code < 57 || code > 127) {
  return;
}

evt.preventDefault();
```

}).number(true, 2);

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ufupul/2/)

Comment: i'm getting an error **Syntax error on token "_$tag_________________$tag________________", invalid AssignmentOperator** on second if statement.

Comment: @user2071789 It works fine in the `jsbin` example I've added at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

use this function to check each input

Answer (score 0):

refer this post to restrict text box to numeric only

[Numeric Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Or else you can write your own regular expression on keyup event and validate the input.

Happy coding